# Differential equation using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solve $y'+4y+5\int_0^xydx=e^{-x}$, $y(0)=0$

I am asked to solve the following problem using Laplace transforms. I know how to solve this using the regular method but unsure as to how to solve it via the Laplace method and would really appreciate some help.

If we derive the expression then we will obtain

$y''+4y'=-e^{-x}-5x$

Now we can apply the laplace transform.

$L[y'']+L[4y']=L[-e^{-x}]+L[-5x]$

We know that

$L[y']=pL[y]-y(0)$ and $L[y'']=p^2L[y]-py(0)-y'0$

$L[e^{-x}]=-\frac{1}{p+a}$ and $L[-5x]=-5L[x]=\frac{-5}{p^2}$

Combining all the above yields

$p^2L[y]-py(0)-y'0+4(pL[y]-y(0)=-\frac{1}{p+a}-\frac{5}{p^2}$

From here I don't really know how to simplify and also what is $y'(0)=0$

Comment: Have you taken any Laplace transform of the equation?

Comment: I derived and took the transform, could you please tell me if I am on the correct path and if so help me finish it please? @MichaelMcGovern

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. After you take the Laplace transform, you solve the resultant algebraic equation and take its inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I didn't see that you had edited your question while I was responding.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern thats okay, I seem to be making mistakes and cannot obtain the correct answer, do you think you could help me finish the problem please?

Comment: also  laplace for $e^{-x}=\frac{1}{p+1}$

Comment: @serg_1 how did you get 5xy?

Comment: oh, sorry for that statement.

Comment: i think you need to know $y'(0)$ in your question as well

Comment: Your derivative for the integral is incorrect. And you can find $y'(0)$ by plugging in $x=0$ into the first equation.

Comment: @Cocomos is it not the fundamental theorem, so when we derive the integral we just plug in the upper bound?

Comment: @thisisme If your integral is $\int^x_0y(x)\,dx$ then apply Leibniz rule to obtain the correct derivative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule If you meant $\int^x_0y(\xi)\,d\xi$ then it is the fundamental theorem.

Comment: @Cocosmos by plugging $x=0$ what is $y'(0)$?

Comment: @serg_1 Fundamental theorem is $\frac{d}{dx}\int^x_0y(\xi)\,d\xi=y(x)$ Plugging in $x=0$ gives $y'(0)+4y(0)+5\int^0_0y(\xi)\,d\xi=e^{-0}$. Integral is zero. You know $y(0)=0$. Thus $y'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $Y(s)=\mathcal{L}_x\{y\}(s)$ to be the Laplace transform of $y$. Taking the Laplace transform of the DE gives,
$$sY(s) - y(0) + 4Y(s) + \frac{5}{s}Y(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}\;.\tag{1}$$
After algebraic gymnastics we can obtain an expression for $Y$,
$$Y(s)=\frac{s}{s^3+5s^2+9s+5}\;.\tag{2}$$
Taking inverse Laplace transform gives the not so pretty result (used Mathematica for this):
$$y(x)=-\frac{e^{-x}}{2} - \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{i}{4}\right) e^{(-2 - i)x} \left((-2 - i) + (1 + 2 i) e^{2 i x}\right)\tag{3}$$
This may seem frightening at first, but if you are clever enough, then you will see that you can rewrite this in terms of sine and cosine using $\sin(x)=\frac{i}{2}(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-ix}+e^{ix})$ to get,
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-2x}\left(3\sin(x)+\cos(x)-e^x\right)\;.\tag{4}$$
Plugging this into the original DE verifies it is the solution. In hindsight, you can probably use partial fractions on equation $(2)$ to avoid my Mathematica route for finding the inverse Laplace transform.

Note taking your method by first evaluating the derivative of the differential equation to obtain the new second order equation
$$y''+4y'+5y=-e^{-x},\quad y(0)=0,\quad y'(0)=1$$
where $y'(0)$ is found by plugging in $x=0$ into the original equation (see comments on post above) and then taking the Laplace transform of this second order DE ends up yielding the same answer.